# Possibility to cache computationally expensive .fit() method of a scikit-learn estimator?

Tags: python, caching, scikit-learn

I am using [`sklearn.ensemble.BaggingClassifier`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.BaggingClassifier.html) to fit 1000 estimators on my data. I wonder if it is possible to cache the `.fit()` method of this class so that the output of the `.fit()` method can simply be cached once the script has been run for the first time?

Take this as an example:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import BaggingClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

rng = np.random.RandomState(42)
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000,n_features=4,n_informative=2,
                           n_redundant=0,random_state=rng,shuffle=False)

# initialize bagging classifier
clf = BaggingClassifier(base_estimator=LogisticRegression(),n_estimators=1000,random_state=rng)
result = clf.fit(X,y).estimators_[0].coef_
```

**EDIT:**

The answers below seem to give answers on how to cache results **within** the fitting process, i.e. when fitting n estimators, try to use pre-computed results from already fitted classifiers. Instead, what I am looking for is a way to cache the **whole process**. I wonder if could use `sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline` for this? The adapted code would look like this (happy to receive feedback if this is right):

```py
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
# initialize bagging classifier
clf = BaggingClassifier(base_estimator=LogisticRegression(),n_estimators=1000,random_state=rng)
pipe = Pipeline([('clf',clf)],memory='./cache')
result = pipe.fit(X,y)._final_estimator.estimators_[0].coef_
```

Comment: could you be more specific about what you mean with caching the `fit()` method? When you're fitting on the same dataset you can use `warm_start`, but if you want to fit on different batches of data `partial_fit` works

Comment: Does having the fitted classifier not suffice? If not, in what way?

Comment: Sorry, could you be more specific? I am not sure if I understand your question

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `warm_start` to reuse the solution of the previous call to fit and add more estimators to the ensemble.

With this solution you can compute estimators by batch and save the current model states.

Below is an example of `warm_start`:

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.ensemble import BaggingClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=100, n_features=4,
                           n_informative=2, n_redundant=0,
                           random_state=0, shuffle=False)

clf = BaggingClassifier(base_estimator=SVC(),
                        n_estimators=10, random_state=0, warm_start=True)

for i in range(5):
    clf.fit(X, y)
    print(f'Iteration {i} score with {clf.n_estimators}: {clf.score(X, y)}')
    clf.n_estimators += 10
```

This will output the following:

```
Iteration 0 score with 10: 0.92
Iteration 1 score with 20: 0.93
Iteration 2 score with 30: 0.92
Iteration 3 score with 40: 0.92
Iteration 4 score with 50: 0.92
```

Comment: But If I get that right, this would not cache the whole fitting process? In other words, when you fit 1000 estimators on your dataset, then close  and restart the python session and call `.fit()` again, it wouldn't cache previously computed results right?

Comment: If you want to save and restart the fitting afterward you should serialize your model before restarting python. Then you could load the model and continue the training process.